# compare each character in string to one lookup chcarcter

Tags: r

I have long vector of strings.
e.g. `c('aecde1234e', 'ewert6e8e0')`

I want to compare each chacter in each string to one specific lookup character, e.g. `'e'`.

The goal is to have a long vector of strings with the result
e.g. `c('0100100001', '1010001010')`.

How can I write such a comparison in R ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> string <- c('aecde1234e', 'ewert6e8e0')
> sapply(strsplit(string, ""), function(x) paste(as.numeric(x == "e"), collapse = "") )
[1] "0100100001" "1010001010"
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this approach. Suppose I want to compare the string to another string of the same length and find matches - how should I change the function of comparison?

Comment: I'll post that as a separate question...

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
x <- c('aecde1234e', 'ewert6e8e0')
gsub("e", "1", gsub("[^e]", "0", x))

# [1] "0100100001" "1010001010"
```

Comment: Slight edit to this will make it flexible to deal with multiple character translations that are not going to `0` - `chartr("e", "1", gsub("[^e]", 0, x))`